# Word that means "obsession with publishing"

Tags: single-word-requests

I once heard a word, derived from Latin or Greek elements, construed to describe a person who has an obsession with being published. What word might that have been? For example, what would you call some who has an inexplicable need to blog?

Comment: When I saw this question, **O'Reilly** sprang to mind, but you meant from the other side of the business.

Comment: I would call that an *academic*.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Someone who is obsessed with writing is a [*graphomaniac*](http://www.wordnik.com/words/graphomaniac), from Greek *graphein*, "write", and *mania*, "madness":

> One who is constantly writing, either letters to friends or to the newspapers, or stories and works of fiction, driven thereto either by an exaggerated idea of the importance of what he writes or by an insane impulse.

To round it up, here's a link to the [Wikipedia article on graphomania](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphomania):

> Outside the psychiatric definitions of graphomania and related conditions, the word is used more broadly to label the urge and need to write excessively, whether professional or not.

That being said, as far as blogs are concerned, how about *blogomaniac*? You probably won't find it in any dictionary (yet), but it is pretty much self-explanatory, and as a free bonus, it sounds and looks very similar to [*logomaniac*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/logomaniac?r=66), someone who is obsessed with words or talking, from Greek *logos*, "word".

Comment: (see also  http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/logorrhea for a talkative, chatty individual)

Answer (score 5):

*Blogomaniac* in [RegDwight’s answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4754/word-that-means-obsession-with-publishing/4756#4756) is fine, but another option is *blogaholic* or *blogoholic*.

Comment: For those of you addicted to blogahol.

Comment: @John Gietzen: Interestingly, Google shows many more results for “blogaholic” (168,000) than “blogoholic” (28,500) although (as your comment suggests) the suffix -holic originates from “alcoholic.”

Comment: Hooray for backformations.

Answer (score 2):

A person with an inexplicable need to blog might also be defined as having OCD, or someone who really lacks an otherwise constructive hobby.  That said, at its core, blogging is merely writing in electronic form, so "graphomaniac" is a sufficiently good choice.  Logomaniac wasn't in my MW dictionary, so I won't comment on it, except to say, please, everyone, let's not coin one more internet-centric term.